# ASP.NET button click event only works when on Top level master page

Tags: asp.net

I have base.master (top-level), second.master (submaster). A button in the top-level master fires the click event fine, on a page which ues that one master, if its on page where the second.master is used, that button click event doesn't work.

No buttons that I place in the submaster work either, heres the code:

```
protected void afd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var a = "C";
        }

<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="afd" Text="huh" />
```

Base.master directive:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/umbraco/masterpages/default.master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Base.master.cs" Inherits="UmbracoWebsite.masterpages.Base" %>
```

Register.master directive:

```
<%@ Master CodeBehind="~/masterpages/Register.master.cs" Inherits="UmbracoWebsite.masterpages.Register" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpages/Base.master" AutoEventWireup="True" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

By this it means you are wiring up `button_click` event manually and also you are missing button name so i would assume it as `btn1`

so you also need to provide the following line on `Page_Load` of `Page_Init` of the page where using it:

```
btn1.Click += new EventHandler(afd);
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: Nop, that's not working. + Wasn't expecting it to work as I didn't need to do that with the top-level master button

Comment: the you better avoid problems for new and later and use autoeventwireup
by double-clicking the button on design view and provide your logic in the auto-generated method...

Comment: I don't think this is an issue caused by that, its consistently showing the same issue..